# SQL get latest record

Tags: sql, select

Pretty sure my question headline is terrible, but anyways I have a table called invoices and inside that table each invoice has an id and each id had a client id so clients will have multiple invoices. I am trying to get latest invoices remainingbalance, The code I wrote doesnt work, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
SELECT c.clientid,
    c.clientname,
    c.billingdate,
    (SELECT remainingbalance 
     FROM invoice i 
     WHERE i.client = c.clientid) AS remaining
FROM client c
ORDER BY clientname
```

Comment: Latest by what criteria? Being MAX(InvoiceID) or MAX(InvoiceDate)?

Comment: What RDMS you are using?

Comment: I am trying to find out my RDMS....how do I find that out?

Answer (score 5):

Use `INNER JOIN`

**Try this**

UPDATE:
I have revised my answer see if that works

```
 SELECT c.clientid,
 c.clientname,
 c.billingdate,
 d.remainingbalance
 FROM client c 
 INNER JOIN (
             SELECT  clientid,
             MAX(invoiceid) invoiceid
             FROM    invoice
             GROUP BY  clientid
             ) d
 ON c.clientid = d.clientid
 ORDER BY c.clientname
```

Comment: He has multiple rows in the invoice table and he only wants the last one.

Comment: Well I didnt get an error, but it returns multiple clients, I just want the one with the latest id in invoice

Answer (score 3):

Off the bat, try something like

```
SELECT  c.clientid, 
        c.clientname, 
        c.billingdate, 
        (
            SELECT  TOP 1 
                    remainingbalance  
            FROM    invoice i  
            WHERE   i.client = c.clientid
            ORDER BY i.invoiceid DESC
        ) AS remaining 
FROM    client c 
ORDER BY    clientname
```

Which RDMS are you using?

A different approach would be as follows

```
SELECT  c.clientid,  
        c.clientname,  
        c.billingdate,
        rb.remainingbalance
FROM    client c  INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  i.clientid,
                    i.remainingbalance 
            FROM    invoice i INNER JOIN
                    (
                        SELECT  clientid,
                                MAX(invoiceid) invoiceid
                        FROM    invoice
                        GROUP BY    clientid
                    ) m ON  i.invoiceid = m.invoiceid
                        AND i.clientid = m.clientid
        ) rb    ON  c.clientid = rb.clientid
ORDER BY clientname
```

First get the "latest" invoice per client, then get the details required from that invoice and display with the client info.

Comment: The first one gives me a syntax error near '1 i.remainingbalance FROM invoice i WHERE i.client = c.clientid ORDER BY i.invoiceid'

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? and please provide your table schemas.

Comment: trying to find this out...I have a thing called information_schema with alot of tables, where would I find where my RDBMS is?

Comment: MySQL, SQL Server, MS Access, Oracle? Which database are you using? And provide us with the column names in each table, that is the table schema.

Comment: Then rather use the first query example?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15929/discussion-between-user1269625-and-astander)

Answer (score 0):

Order by i.id DESC in your sub select

Comment: So that would then also break your Idea, as more than 1 row could be returned per client...

Comment: then add a LIMIT 1 after DESC